# Modify slider (www.basic-slider.com) to show previous and next slide too

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, slideshow, scroller

I'm quite new to jQuery and I integrated this slider (www.basic-slider.com) in my website.
I would like to know if there is a way to make it show the previous and next image as well as the current image in the same frame.
I mean to make 3 images visible instead of just one.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The slider slides through different list items, so you can add multiple images to one slide:

```
<div id="my-slideshow">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li><img src="image1.png"><img src="image2.png"><img src="image3.png"></li>
        <li><img src="image4.png"><img src="image5.png"><img src="image6.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```